# How I can access variable defined in parent function via Wordpress hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, scope, hook-woocommerce

In general I want this:

```php
function parent () {
    $foo = 'something';
    do_action ('hook');
}

function child () {
    echo $foo;
}

add_action ('hook','child');
```

In particular I want to print the WooCommerce product `$attributes` variable used to make attribute selection drop-down to get the idea what's inside the array and later manipulate this data. The code is:

```php
function 'print_attributes' () {
    global $woocommerce, $attributes;
    print '<pre>';
    print_r ($attributes);
    print '</pre>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','print_attributes');
```

`<pre>` tags are printed on product page but `$attributes` are empty.
As far as I understand my code won't work until I declare `global $attributes` in parent function as well which means modifying WooCommerce template files which I want to avoid.

`$attributes` are called in variable.php template - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php#L22, the hook is placed a few lines later - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php#L26.
Is there any way I can access the variable without modifying WooCommerce code?

I understand I can just override template via child theme, but I am eager to know if this can be done via hook as I'm just learning PHP and Wordpress.

Comment: You should just use instead: `global $product; $attributes = $product->get_attributes(); print_r( $attributes );` inside your `print_attributes()` function.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This will work in this situation, but I want to know if there's a way to do this kind of trick in general. If it is possible to manipulate some variable from parent function via hook. The information in scope section of php website is rather scarce.

Comment: Yes that is possible, but each case will use different hooks ans ways…

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this. So far most hooks I used have no parameters to pass.

Comment: Sorry, but most of them have parameters… Action hooks are to trigger an action when a hook is called… Filter hooks are made to change something, like an argument (a variable)  that is always returned at the end in a hooked function… Your question is not enough clear as you don't explain what you are trying to do and for what purpose…

Answer (score 0):

using your demo code:

```
function parent () {
    $foo = 'something';
    do_action ('hook', $foo);
}

function child ($foo) {
    echo $foo;
}

add_action ('hook','child');
```

You can pass variables into the hook, by default the hook pass the first variable to the executed function, if you need more use like this:

```
function parent () {
    $foo = 'something';
    $bar = 'something';
    $baz = 'something';
    do_action ('hook', $foo, $bar, $baz);
}

function child ($foo, $bar, $baz) {
    echo $foo;
    echo $bar;
    echo $baz;
}

add_action ('hook','child', 10, 3);
```

find more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But the question is how this can be done without altering WooCommerce code.

Comment: In that case, I don't believe it´s possible without modifying the woocommerce template. Did you try without setting $attributes as global in the print attributes function?